# XPath id value changing on every session

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have a payment provider website from which I need to use Selenium to scrape the website, because the API has limited functionality.
The first line is the XPATH of the export button, the code works, but on the next session,
the id changes.

```
#hover over download icon
element_to_hover_over = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="pIFE1qieLu"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/a')

                                                               '//*[@id="LdFYNH7TGe"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/a'
```

The remaining XPath line stays the same, except for the @id sign.
How do I allow for this dynamically changing id field?

Edit: add the html code

```
[<div class="btn-group dropup pull-left">
 <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                                     Entries 1-200 of 8983                                                <span class="caret"></span>
 </a>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
 <li class=""><a class="ajxl" href="/index.php/filter/setPagination/f/KbInvoiceFilter/m/kb_invoice/a/list/nb/10">Display 10 entries</a></li>
 <li class=""><a class="ajxl" href="/index.php/filter/setPagination/f/KbInvoiceFilter/m/kb_invoice/a/list/nb/15">Display 15 entries</a></li>
 <li class=""><a class="ajxl" href="/index.php/filter/setPagination/f/KbInvoiceFilter/m/kb_invoice/a/list/nb/20">Display 20 entries</a></li>
 <li class=""><a class="ajxl" href="/index.php/filter/setPagination/f/KbInvoiceFilter/m/kb_invoice/a/list/nb/25">Display 25 entries</a></li>
 <li class=""><a class="ajxl" href="/index.php/filter/setPagination/f/KbInvoiceFilter/m/kb_invoice/a/list/nb/50">Display 50 entries</a></li>
 <li class=""><a class="ajxl" href="/index.php/filter/setPagination/f/KbInvoiceFilter/m/kb_invoice/a/list/nb/100">Display 100 entries</a></li>
 <li class="active"><a class="ajxl" href="/index.php/filter/setPagination/f/KbInvoiceFilter/m/kb_invoice/a/list/nb/200">Display 200 entries</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>,
 <div class="pull-left">
 <a class="btn bx-noIcon-margin" data-original-title="Export current list" href="/index.php/filter/export/f/KbInvoiceFilter/m/kb_invoice/a/list" onclick="if (!this.getAttribute('disabled')) jq_load_dialog('/index.php/filter/export/f/KbInvoiceFilter/m/kb_invoice/a/list',{autoOpen:false, bgiframe:false, close:'function() { $(this).dialog(\'destroy\'); }', maxHeight:2000, maxWidth:2024, modal:true, resizable:false, title:'Download as Excel file', width:400},'#jqDialog'); return false;" rel="tooltip" title=""><i class="glyphicons download_alt"></i> </a> </div>,
 <div class="pull-left">
 <a class="btn bx-noIcon-margin" data-original-title="Email list documents" href="/index.php/filter/send/f/KbInvoiceFilter/m/kb_invoice/a/list" onclick="if (!this.getAttribute('disabled')) jq_load_dialog('/index.php/filter/send/f/KbInvoiceFilter/m/kb_invoice/a/list',{autoOpen:false, bgiframe:false, close:'function() { $(this).dialog(\'destroy\'); }', maxHeight:2000, maxWidth:2024, modal:true, resizable:false, title:'Email list documents', width:550},'#jqDialog'); return false;" rel="tooltip" title=""><i class="glyphicons envelope"></i> </a> </div>]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you confirm the url?

Comment: the url works for me to get to the page.

Comment: Mate, confirm (state, write) the url of the page, for anyone willing to help you to be able to test it. Yoou need to post a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: oh sorry, it is a subscription company, so we need to have username and password. 
https://www.bexio.com/en-CH/

Comment: We need some of the relevant HTML around the element you are looking for. Surely there is some unique attribute in the element you want or nearby but we can't see it to help you since it's a site that requires a login.

Comment: Just include the html code of the element in question.

Comment: Since you didn't give us the html code snippet, it's hard to figure out which button we're talking about. But if it's a "Contacts" button you can try using: `driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[class="btn bx-noIcon-margin"]')`

Comment: thanks for the comments! it is an export button on the footer of the page, as shown in the image.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to click the export button icon which is child of anchor element then the xpath is

```
//a[@data-original-title="Export current list"]/child:i
```

CSS Selector:

```
a[data-original-title="Export current list"]>i
```

It should also work with xpath

```
//a[@data-original-title="Export current list"]
```